# SLIM 3 Model should have registration method or controller should have it?

Tags: php, pdo, slim-3

```
class User {

protected $db;

public function __construct(PDO $db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}

public function find($id)
{
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
      $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute([':id' => $id]);

      return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

This is my user controller . should I add registration method here or I should use do it in the controller. which is the efficient and professional way to make it right? I am the beginner in MVC model.

Comment: neither; create a service for registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of mvc is seperation of logic, view and model operation, now you can create a simple model to insert or select the data but a controller should exist to perform certain logic such as input validation before and after the data are sent to the models, so in best practice you can have a registration method in the model to add new user and also a registration method in the controller to process input data and call the model to insert the data.